# Linux bash script to get an array of value from a yml file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, yaml

I have an environment.yml like

```yaml
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - flask
  - gunicorn = 0.22.0
  - pandas=0.21.1
  - pip
  - pip:
    - six==1.14.0
    - requests ==2.21.0
    - pytz
```

I want to get all python packages in an array.

```bash
    packagesArray=("flask" "gunicorn" "pandas" "pip" "six" "requests" "pytz" )
```

How can we do that?

Comment: Use https://pyyaml.org/

Answer (score 1):

One way using [`yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/), a handy front end that converts YAML to JSON and then feeds it to [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/):

```bash
readarray -t packagesArray < <(yq -r '.dependencies | .. | select(type == "string") | sub("=.*";"")' environment.yaml)
```

After this, `declare -p packagesArray` will show

```bash
declare -a packagesArray=([0]="flask" [1]="gunicorn " [2]="pandas" [3]="pip" [4]="six" [5]="requests " [6]="pytz")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like the below in python3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import yaml

def read_yaml(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            data_yml = yaml.safe_load(file)
            return data_yml

    except BaseException as e:
        msg = 'Yaml File: ' + str(e)
        print(msg)


data = read_yaml('environment.yml')

for key, value in data.items():
    print(f"\nkey - {key}\nvalue - {value}\n")
```

if you still want to use bash then check out the below link:

[read yaml bash](https://gist.github.com/pkuczynski/8665367)